# Tensorflow reporting wrong AUC

Tags: tensorflow, evaluation, auc

I have an issue while using AUC from tensorflow library. I train my model (convolutional neural network) per batch ( i do not use a validation set) and after each epoch I use an independent test set to obtain my evaluations. The problem lies within AUC evaluation.

In each batch I calculate AUC/Accuracy/Loss/Precision/Recall/F1_score for the training set and then I aggregate the mean of these scores. When I try to do the same for the test set I again calculate the same scores. I notice that all scores except AUC have different values. I think it is not correct test's loss function to increase and AUC to increase as well. And the problem is that test's AUC is almost identical to training's AUC (even though their accuracy, loss error are completely different).

```
    with tf.name_scope("output"):
        W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_filters_total, num_classes], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]), name="b")
        scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(h_drop, W, b, name="scores")
        predictions = tf.argmax(scores, 1, name="predictions")
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W, name="l2_loss")
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(b, name="l2_loss")
        tf.summary.histogram("l2", l2_loss)
        tf.summary.histogram("weigths", W)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)

    with tf.name_scope("auc_score"):
        # labelOut = tf.argmax(y_place_holder, 1)
        probability = tf.nn.softmax(scores)
        # auc_scoreTemp = streaming_auc(y_place_holder, probability, curve="PR")
        auc_scoreTemp = tf.metrics.auc(y_place_holder, probability, curve="PR")
        auc_score = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(auc_scoreTemp, tf.float32), name="auc_score")
        tf.summary.scalar("auc_score", auc_score)

    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        labelOut = tf.argmax(y_place_holder, 1)
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(predictions, tf.argmax(y_place_holder, 1), name="correct_prediction")
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name="accuracy")
        tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)


    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    for batch in batches:
        x_batch, y_batch = list(zip(*batch))
        _,  accuracy_train, auc_training,  loss_train,  prec_batch, recall_batch, f1_batch \
            = sess.run([train_step,  accuracy, auc_score,  cross_entropy,  precision_mini_batch,
                        recall_mini_batch, f1_score_min_batch], feed_dict={x_place_holder: x_batch,
                                                                           y_place_holder: y_batch,
                                                                           emb_place_holder: vocab_inv_emb_dset,
                                                                           dropout_keep_prob: dropout_rate})
    ...
       for test_batch in test_batches:
                auc_test = None
                x_test_batch, y_test_batch = list(zip(*test_batch))

                accuracy_test, loss_test,  auc_test = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy, auc_score],
                       feed_dict={x_place_holder: x_test_batch,
                       y_place_holder: y_test_batch,
                       emb_place_holder: vocab_inv_emb_dset_val,
                       dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
```

I also tried to use streaming_auc which returns always 1.

**EDIT**

In the end of every epoch I reset the local variables by running:

```
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

But the first batch outputs really bad results. After the first batch I get normal results from test set which are not close to the training results. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but results seem more realistic this way.

Answer (score 0):

All of the `tf.metrics` return a value *and* an updating op (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc)). So as described [here](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/contrib.metrics.md) you want to use the updating op to accumulate values and then evaluate `auc_score` to retrieve the accumulated value, something like this:

```
...
auc_score, auc_op = tf.metrics.auc(y_place_holder, probability, curve="PR")
...
for batch in batches:
  sess.run([train_step,  accuracy, auc_op,  cross_entropy,...)
...
py_auc = sess.run(auc)
```

**EDIT -- toy example showing tf.metrics.auc and tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import metrics
batch_sz = 100
noise_mag = 0.5
nloop = 10

tf.set_random_seed(0)

batch_x = tf.random_uniform([batch_sz, 1], 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32)
noise = noise_mag * tf.random_normal([batch_sz, 1])
batch_y = tf.sigmoid(tf.to_float(batch_x) + noise)

auc_val, auc_accum = tf.metrics.auc(batch_x, batch_y)

#note: contrib.metrics.streaming_auc reverses labels, predictions
auc_val2, auc_accum2 = metrics.streaming_auc(batch_y, batch_x)   

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(nloop):
        _ = sess.run([auc_accum, auc_accum2])

    auc, auc2 = sess.run([auc_val, auc_val2])
    print('Accumulated AUC = ', sess.run(auc_val))  #0.9238014
    print('Accumulated AUC2 = ', sess.run(auc_val)) #0.9238014
```

Comment: I tried the approach you suggest. I use auc_op in each batch and in the end of batches I call the auc_score. But the problem remains for streaming_auc (I get always results = 1 for both training and testing, even though I changed num_threshold). For metrics.auc (not streaming_auc) again I receive very similar values but in this case the first batch has OK results.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but I added a self-contained example to my answer that shows functionality of the ops

Comment: I read somewhere that AUC is based on local variables so you need to reset local variables before using it in a new test set.